# Function within function in JavaScript - Need to understand this code:

Tags: javascript

I have below code within a function called render. How do I call the str variable value outside render function?

Also, please can you explain below code? I'm fairly new to js and head is hurting looking at the function calls having functions as a parameter.

My understanding is that app.getList is an object which takes function as a parameter? but it is not returning anything. Sorry, I'm lost here.

```
app.getList("FieldList", function(reply){
    var str = "";
    $.each(reply.qFieldList.qItems, function(index, value) {
        str +=  value.qName + ' ';
    });
    console.log(str);
});
```

Full Code:

```js
define(["jquery",
    //mashup and extension interface
    "qlik",
    //add stylesheet
    "text!./css/mystyle.css",
    "client.utils/state",
    "client.utils/routing"
  ],
  function($, qlik, cssContent, clientState, clientRedirect) {


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // function redirect (sheetId){
    // clientRedirect.goToSheet(sheetId, Object.keys(clientState.States)[clientState.state])
    // }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    var render = function($elem, layout) {


      var html = '',
        app = qlik.currApp();


      //get list of tab objects and insert into div
      app.getAppObjectList('sheet', function(arrayitem) {


        //for each sheet in the app, create a list item
        $.each(arrayitem.qAppObjectList.qItems, function(myindex, myvalue) {


          //include the sheet id as the list item id to be used as a reference for active sheet
          html += '<li id="' + myvalue.qInfo.qId + '">'; // onClick="redirect(' + value.qInfo.qId + ');


          //wrap anchor tag to be used by bootstrap styling
          html += '<a>';


          //give the link the same name as the sheet
          html += myvalue.qData.title;

          html += '</a>';
          html += '</li>';
        });


        html += '</ul></div>';


        html += "<button id='myButton'> Click Me!! </button>";


        console.log(arrayitem.qAppObjectList);
        console.log(html);


        //insert html into the extension object
        return $elem.html(html);
      });

      /* Test Code Start from here */

      app.getList("FieldList", function(reply) {
        var str = "";
        $.each(reply.qFieldList.qItems, function(key, value) {
          str += value.qName + ' ';
        });
        console.log(str);
      });

    };
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/


    return {
      /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
      paint: function($element, layout) {

        console.count();

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $(function() {
          $element.html("#myButton").click(function() {
            // for(var mynum = 1; mynum <= 5; mynum++){
            //   alert('button test' + mynum);
            // };
          });
        });
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/


        render($element, layout);
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
      }
    };


  });
```

Comment: *How do I call the str variable value outside render function?* What render function? You don't have a function called `render` in that code. You don't even use the word render in the code!

Comment: *Also, please can you below code?* — I have no idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: without knowing anything about what `app.getList` actually does, I'm going to assume it's making an asynchronous request to a server, which means you can only use `reply` *inside* the callback function, though you can pass it to a different function, like you're doing with `console.log(str)`.

Comment: *My understanding is that app.getList is an object which takes function as a parameter?* Yes.

Comment: *but it is not returning anything* — No, it isn't. Without seeing its definition we can't tell you what it is doing though.

Comment: @Quentin - Apologies for not sharing full code and for fast typing. Hope this makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.getList` is probably *asynchronous* (meaning it runs in the background).  The function you've passed to it is a *callback*.  That function will be ran at some point in the future, once the AJAX call (or whatever asynchronous method is ran) is done.

Your callback is passed `reply`, which is the "return" value from `getList()`.  You *cannot* access `str` from outside of this function.  You need to do whatever code with `reply` and/or `str` in that function only.

Comment: Hi - Thank you for taking time to answer. I've posted full code now. Does your response still apply to the code I posted?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `app.getList` is asynchronous, so what I said still applies.  Actually... what is `app` (what is `qlik`)?  What is `app.getList()`?

Comment: qlik is interface loader for Qlik Sense API. 

I think app.getList() method gets data from the active app.

Here is the documentation link: https://help.qlik.com/sense/2.1/en-US/developer/#../Subsystems/APIs/Content/MashupAPI/qlik-app-interface.htm%3FTocPath%3DQlik%2520Sense%2520APIs%2520and%2520SDKs%7CCapability%2520APIs%7Cqlik.app%2520(App%2520API)%7C_____0

Comment: Looking at the code. Please can you suggest the concepts I need to understand to fully understand the above code? I wanted to learn and not looking for short cut approach. My challenge is that I don't know what I don't know. Many thanks again.

Comment: @DV27: Have a look here: https://help.qlik.com/sense/2.1/en-US/developer/#../Subsystems/APIs/Content/MashupAPI/Methods/getList-method.htm  `getList()` takes a "callback" function as its 2nd parameter, it also returns a promise.  That means that it's doing some work (possibly an AJAX call) in the background and will call your function at some later point in the future (like an event).  When your function is called, that means `getList()` is finished, but it also means your `render` function had finished a long time ago.  All work needs to be done in that callback.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into Callback concept. I will use JavaScript Is Sexy article.